# How come this arrow function has no initialiser? Is this syntax React exclusive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Can someone please explain how arrow functions syntax works?
Why does onInputChange have no const, let, or var before it?
I am trying to understand, but everywhere I look I can only find syntax similar to this one:

```
let arrowFunct = (a) => {a+1};
```

This makes sense. It creates a variable that is assigned what the arrow function returns.

On the other hand, onInputChange from the example below does not have any declaration. Can somebody please explain?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: ''
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Particles className='particles' params={particleOptions}/>
        <Navigation />
        <Logo />
        <Rank />
        <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />
        {/*
        <FaceRecognition />*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I do have another question that is more about React. "event" gets passed down from React.Component, right? It is a prop passed down from the Component class, and it gets created when the super() function runs inside the constructor.

Comment: That's a field declaration

Comment: This is an example of a [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). `event` is not a prop, it is just a parameter to a function. When the inputChange event happens, the event object will be passed in to that function.

Comment: After having looked at the documentation for class fields, it has become more clear what that syntax meant. It is a way to create class methods, without making the constructor look busy. I do still have a question. Do class properties have types (like let, var, or const)? And can methods like onInputChange have types associated to them?

Comment: Methods are functions stored in object properties. `let`, `var` and `const` are form declaring variables, not object properties.

Comment: Methods can have types associated with them in so much as anything in JavaScript can have a type associated with it (i.e. not really as JS uses duck typing everywhere).

Comment: As I understand, objects and classes in JS are somewhat different. Classes have inheritance, properties, constructor, and their syntax is quite different. And when using arrow functions like this ```const arrFct = (a) => {a+1};```, arrFct is an object, a variable, or a function?

Comment: `arrFct` is a variable which holds a function which is also an object. "variable" has sort of a loose meaning. It could refer to the variable name, the variable value or even the pair.

Answer (score -1):

this is not a function, this is a methode you can learn more about Object oriented and prototype oriented online.

The this is the 'function' is only for this object (so it's a methode) and so this is the way to declare it

By the way a function can also be a variable so the syntaxe

```
  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

can be confusing but in fact, it's a real thing, the attribute onInputChange is this function, it's NOT the result of this function, this variable is the function